# Problem changing the main activity in Android studio project

Tags: java, android

I have created the MainActivity for my Android studio project, but after creating it I am adding a Login screen that I want to be the starting activity when the app launches. I changed the AndroidManifest.xml file to include the correct intent-filters for the login activity.

The app launches correctly with the login activity, but the problem is that now when I proceed to the MainActivity the buttons and fragments inside of it don't work anymore. The buttons don't respond to being clicked, and the fragments just don't appear at all.

Here is my code for the Android manifest file. All I changed was I switched .Login and .MainActivity

When I switch them back everything in MainActivity works correctly.

Is there something else I need to change for all the functionality of MainActivity to work correctly, even when it's not the starting activity when the app launches?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".LocationService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Your manifest looks correct. Can you please share the code of MainActivity, and also check with debugger what portions of it are reachable? Also, a good idea is to put activities after each other, for better readability of your manifest file.

Comment: realized my mistake. I used setContentView instead of startActivity in the on click listener to switch from login to main activity. Pretty dumb mistake but thanks for the help